# onHover event on material ui component is not rendering icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, material-ui, event-handling

I am currently trying to render a delete icon on an Material UI component, to be more specific, the MenuItem component. I have created a state field in the component's state and set it to false(this.state.isHovering). The idea is that when I hover over the account item, I want to render the delete icon, and when I hover off, it is supposed to go away. I impleneted these event listeners using onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave and attached them over to the MenuItem. I then made it so that the icon only shows when `this.state.isHovering` is true. However, when I hover over the MenuItem, it does not render. However, if I just implemented the icon without having the state get involved, it renders. I also console logged in the event handlers to make sure that the event is being registered and it does console log both when hovering in and out. Please see my code. Thanks!

```
  handleMouseEnter = () => {
    this.setState({
      isHovering: true,
    })
  }

    handleMouseLeave = () => {
    this.setState({
      isHovering: true,
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few issues with your code:

1. the state is never defined
2. you don't properly update the state
3. You don't properly conditionally check/use the state
4. Lots of bugs in the code you provided (looks like an incomplete copy paste)

You can use [reactHooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to help define your state and setState functions

This is my best answer, but the code you provided is missing the account variable and a lot of the referenced functions, so it is incomplete.  But it should help with your state issues

```
import React, { Component, Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import { Typography, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
import AccountTypeIcon from './AccountTypeIcon';


class PortDashSideBar extends Component {
  const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState(false);
  handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setIsHovering(true);
  }

  handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsHovering(false);
  }

  return <MenuItem
    onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
    onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
    className={account.id === currentAccountId ? classes.selectedAccount : classes.unselectedAccount}
    hover
    name={account.name}
    key={account.id}
    onClick={ () => this.setCurrentAccount(account.id) }>
    <TableCell className={classes.cellAccountIcon}>
      <AccountTypeIcon type={this.getAccountById(account.id).type} />
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell className={classes.cellName}>
      <Typography className={classes.accountName}>
        {account.label}
      </Typography>
      <Typography>
        <span>
          {this.getHoldingsForAccount(account.id)}
        </span>
        {
          isHovering ? <Icon>delete</Icon> : null
        }
      </Typography>
    </TableCell>
  </MenuItem>;
}
```